# Call macros based on characters of a filename

Tags: vba, excel

How can I call macros based on the left n characters of a filename?

Details:
I get emailed many files per month whose names contain a few characters followed by a date or serial number.

For example
- Accounts receivable files are named ARDET 25-01-16.xls, ARDET 19-01-16.xls , ARDET 31-12-15.xls and so on
- Invoicing files are named Bkg_Inv_01.xls, Bkg_Inv_02.xls, Bkg_Inv_03.xls and so on

I have recorded various macros to run on these files. For example, I have Sub ARDET() and Sub Bkg_Inv() to handle the above files.

I want to create a single macro to call the above Subs if the first 5 characters of the filename matches certain text.

The code I am looking for needs to be roughly in the following syntax:

```
Sub Call_Macro_if_leftn_is()

' Making variables

This_File_name  = Currently open file's filename

n = InputBox("Enter the total number of characters from the left of the filename to match")

y = Left n characters of This_File_name


'If Then statements to call other macros

If y = ARDET
Call ARDET()

Else if y = Bkg_I
Call Bkg_Inv()

Else if y = PDC_I
Call PDC_Inv()

Else Msgbox "Filename does not match specified characters"

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you can use [Instr](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Instr+VBa&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=aoCsVpzfPNWQuASkybaICA) function to match a part of the string or you can use [Left or Right](http://www.homeandlearn.org/left_and_right_functions.html) functions to get the first n characters from start or end of a string and then use it to test for a match

Answer (score 1):

I'd try a set-up something like this:

```
Sub RunCodeBasedOnFileName()
    Dim fileID As String

    fileID = VBA.Left$(ThisWorkbook.Name, 5)

    If fileID = "ARDET" Then
        ARDET
    ElseIf fileID = "Bkg_I" Then
        Bkg_I
    ElseIf fileID = "PDC_I" Then
        PDC_I
    Else
        MsgBox "This file is of unknown origin!"
    End If

End Sub

Sub ARDET()
    'Do stuff
End Sub

Sub Bkg_I()
    'Do stuff
End Sub

Sub PDC_I()
    'Do stuff
End Sub
```

- You don't need to use `Call` or have the parentheses `()` when calling a sub
- I'd avoid getting people to input the first 5 characters - instead get it programmatically

The only bit I am unclear about is where you are running this code from and how you are iterating over the files that you are sent?

Where I have `ThisWorkBook` this requires the code to be running in the actual file. I think you'll need to modify that e.g. you loop over a bunch of files in a folder and access the filename that way.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Alex. I will test your code and tell you how it works.

I get such files through email atleast 10 times a day. I run my macros on files before I store them in folders named by month and category of file.

But coming to think of it, your idea of iterating through files in a folder is great ! Could you have the same code iterate over all files in a folder, and preferably, its sub folders as well?

My files are stored in folders in a hierarchy that goes like 
- "C:\Dropbox\Work\2016\Jan\ARDET Jan" or 
- "C:\Dropbox\Work\2016\Jan\BkgInv Jan"

Comment: Yes - easy to iterate over folders and sub folders. Lots of examples on this site if you search for it. Good luck

Comment: Thanks. I found a way to iterate over subfolders. But how can we modify the code to work on files that contain a certain string in the filename rather than use the left characters of the filename.

Comment: Look at the `InStr` function. That will let you find text within a string.